# Use a different service at module import

Tags: angular, angular-services

Here a simple implementation example of my issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqy1lk

I've two pages that import **test-generic** module with a specific provided service (using ForChild) that inherit of **TestGenericService** service.

I use **testMethod** in each service to display in which page module, the component **Generic** was called.

As you can see in the *stackblitz* preview the "page1" link display **Page2** instead of "Page1" string. And the page2 link display the correct string **Page2**.

It's seems that angular only take the last **forChild** call of **TestGenericModule**, in this case when **Page2module** is imported after **Page1Module**

What wrong with my usage of ForChild on providing Service?

Is is possible to import a module inside anothers modules, by provinding a specific service to inject, for the imported module scope only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqy1lk

I just had to define which provider I want to use on the component level (providers) instead of the module level by using forChild.

Now the Service Injection is correct from which component (Page1 or Page2) from where I've my TestGeneric component.